# what the diagram demonstrate?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

[image: 11]

I am completely lost in the question, could anyone tell me what is going on here?

Comment: Number 3 is written so ... truly amazing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture shown is "originally" a $n\times (n+1)$ rectangle.  After cutting the rectangle into two equivalent pieces, you should be able to observe that the two pieces have $1$ square in the first row (or column), $2$ squares in the second row (or column), then $3,4,\dots$

So ultimately this picture illustrates that:

$$1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

The RHS, represents those two pieces; while the LHS, is the row or columns that you can count from each of those pieces.

Answer (score 3):

The illustration gives a combinatorial proof of the summation identity $$1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$  The number of squares in one of the triangles is $$1+2+\cdots+n$$ and the two triangles together contain $n(n+1)$ squares.